# How to get specific records in database laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I developed a project using Laravel, that student's can select their own schedule from `8:00 AM - 10:00 PM` now in my *teacher_tbl* it has a field name `shifts` which it have a data of `am or pm`.

I labelled the `8:00 AM - 5:00 PM` as **am** and `1:00 PM - 10:00 PM` as **pm** so that I can easily fetch. Now my problem is how can I get *teachers* when the student select the time between `1:00 PM - 5:00 PM` because.. it's both under `AM` & `PM`.

This is how I get the student's selected time from selected option element.

```
if ($selectedTime == "8:00") 
    $shift= 'AM';
else if ($selectedTime == "9:00") 
    $shift= 'AM';
...
else if ($selectedTime == "1:00") 
    $shift= ""; //what should I label this?
...
// and so on...

Teacher::where('shifts', $shift)->get();
```

Here is my question.. What should I label to `1:00 - 5:00` is it AM or PM. Here is the part that I can't get it.

The **AM Teachers** is only available at **8AM-5PM**, and **PM Teachers** is **1PM-10PM**

Assumed that students selected `2PM`, it should be both AM & PM teachers will be fetch, but when selected the `6PM` is should only fetch the PM Teachers.

I am very confused. Hope anyone can help me..

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are trying to get a teacher that has a shift of either AM, PM, or both based on student's selection.

If that is the case then you can simply use [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#where-clauses) like so:

```
// your shift variable here should be an array. ['AM'], ['PM'], or ['AM','PM'] should be the value
if ($selectedTime == "8:00") 
    $shift= ['AM'];
else if ($selectedTime == "9:00") 
    $shift= ['AM'];
...
else if ($selectedTime == "1:00") 
    $shift= ['AM','PM']; //what should I label this?
...
// and so on...

$teachers = Teacher::whereIn('shifts', $shift)->get();
```

Also, as a side note, i suggest not doing a really long if else statement as it can get out of hand quickly, you can try using a [Switch case](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) at the very least or use something like carbon for time comparison.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I updated my question above. Hope my question is clear.

Comment: @Jin i have updated my answer, please give it a try :)

Comment: Yeah dude, I am still new in Laravel too. I will just update my code. thank you for suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($selectedTime == "8:00") 
    $shift= ['AM'];
else if ($selectedTime == "9:00") 
    $shift= ['AM'];
...
else if ($selectedTime == "1:00") 
    $shift= ['AM','PM']; //Select both AM and PM
...
// and so on...

Teacher::whereIn('shifts', $shift)->get();
```

This should solve your problem based on the understanding of your problem statement.

Happy to help!!!